# Live Validation Mutually exclusive fields

Tags: javascript, validation, livevalidation

I am trying to validate two fields using `LiveValidation` but I can't seem to find anything on it anywhere.

I am trying to make one or the other of the `Email` and `Mobile` fields required so that when one is filled in the other does not need to be, but both *may* be entered.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Email = new LiveValidation("Email", {validMessage: "", onlyOnBlur: true});
Email.add(Validate.Presence, {failureMessage:"This field is required"});
Email.add(Validate.Format, {pattern: /^[ ]*([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})[ ]*$/i,    failureMessage: "A valid email address is required"});

var mobile = new LiveValidation("mobile", {validMessage: "", onlyOnBlur:    true});mobile.add(Validate.Presence, {failureMessage:"This field is required"});

var discussion = new LiveValidation("discussion", {validMessage: "", onlyOnBlur: true});discussion.add(Validate.Presence, {failureMessage:"This field is required"});
</script>
```

Comment: _Mutually Exclusive_ would mean that when one is filled the other is _not allowed_ to be filled.  Do you mean that "at least one of Email or Mobile is required, or both"?

Comment: Only one is required, but they can give both if they want to

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it, but you'd have to hack it a bit. With the LiveValidation library, there's no function under the LiveValidation class that returns a constant or boolean indicating that a field is validated. However, you can check that the validation message has been added to the DOM. For instance, say I have the code, ->

```
var f1 = new LiveValidation('f1');
f1.add( Validate.Presence );
```

Now, I want to make sure that f1 is validated. To do this, I would get the parent element of field 'f1', check for elements with the class 'LV_valid', and go from there. My code would look something like, ->

```
function isValidated (field) {
    var element = document.getElementById (field);
    for (var i in element.parentElement.getElementsByClassName ("LV_valid")) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that there's no way of identifying if the LV field that you retrieved was the one that corresponded with your field. You might have to write your own validation code or make a modified version of the library. That's all the input I can provide right now, hopefully it's valid.